# Optimization Library in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, linear-programming

I am writing a machine learning/classification algorithm in ruby, and I would like to optimize for some of the parameters in my algorithm. I have 4 variables, p, x, y, and z, where 0 <= x + y + z <= 1 and 0 <= p <= 1. Clearly, this is an optimization problem.

However, because the thing I am trying to maximize is not a mathematical function per se (i.e. cannot be represented in a matrix, no obvious notion of derivative, etc) but rather a call to a program, where the return value is its classification accuracy, I cannot find the right tool for the job. The program takes about 5 minutes per run, so it's super expensive to begin with. Does anyone know of any ruby libraries that will do what I need? Or do I need to switch to another language? (In which case, how do I optimize a program written in ruby using a script in another language?)

Things I've tried/looked at:

rglpk - has linear programming, but my objective function is (clearly) non linear

SciRuby - not fully developed (e.g. doesn't have an equivalent for SciPy.optimize)

rbgsl - so close. I can specify my own objective function (nonlinear). I can specify a step function and multiple variables to be optimized. But I can seem to specify bounds on the variables, despite the c version of multimin having an argument to specify those constraints. Am I missing something?

Comment: `...but rather a call to a program, where the return value is its classification accuracy` -- That's a function.

Comment: A quick/hacky way to specify bounds is to add functions that make answers outside those bounds non-optimal.

Comment: I would suggest editing the question. Since your objective function is (as far as I can tell) a black box you can't use linear programming to solve your problem. You're looking for something like optimization via simulation, derivative-free optimization, or something else. Can you specify more about your objective function? Is it noisy? Is it expensive? How many function calls can you afford to do when doing your optimization?

Comment: @NeilSlater tried that actually but the optimizer gest confused